# Upgrade C++ VS 2005 Project to VS 2010 Causes LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, lnk2019

I'm attempting to upgrade a project written in C++ in VS 2005 to VS 2010. After I run the upgrade wizard, I try and build the project and I get a bunch of LNK2019 errors.

For further clarification, this projects builds a DLL which is used by our Product Lifecycle Management system named Teamcenter.

At this point, I'm kind of stumped. The project compiles in VS 2005 in Debug without any issues.

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet of the error:

Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EMH_store_error_s1 referenced in function "int __cdecl AFCC_create_ai(struct EPM_action_message_s)" (?AFCC_create_ai@@YAHUEPM_action_message_s@@@Z)    C:\Users\kevmoo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AFCC\AFCC\AFCC\AFCC_action_handlers.obj   AFCC
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EPM_add_attachments referenced in function "int __cdecl AFCC_create_ai(struct EPM_action_message_s)" (?AFCC_create_ai@@YAHUEPM_action_message_s@@@Z)   C:\Users\kevmoo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AFCC\AFCC\AFCC\AFCC_action_handlers.obj   AFCC

Comment: Which DLL is VS2010 linking with?

Comment: There happens to be about 25 LIBs that VS is linking with, I can list them if you think they will be useful.

Comment: Have you checked the paths for DLL loading?  Are the DLLs in the place where VS2010 is looking for them?

Comment: Hi, thank you but I have resolved this issue, there were some DLL/LIB files missing that was causing my problem. It was a bit overwhelming because of the sheer volume of them but I was able to figure it out.!